# Adding html attributes for block

Tags: 7, blocks

I want to add HTML attributes for my block by using `hook_block_view_alter`. Any suggestions/code snippets for this?

Comment: exactly what do you want to do? add HTML markup and attributes to block content ot  to Block itself?

Answer (score 2):

If you need for D7, [Block Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_attributes) module or if you just need class [Block Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class)

Answer (score 1):

Instead use [Markup](https://www.drupal.org/project/markup) module. it easily integrates with the form. I am guessing u use D7...

> This module adds the ability for site admins to add "Markup" widgets
>   to the form. These essentially let designers of cck content-types
>   insert additional markup into the node/edit form to display to
>   content-authors. This is the equivalent of adding additional elements
>   to $form of the type '#markup'.
>
> The module does not add anything to the $node object for the content
>   being created, and utilizes form_alter to remove unnecessary fields
>   from the '_content_admin_field' form when this widget is being
>   created.

Comment: @No Sssweat Then how do u plan doing it...??? The question is quite unclear....

Comment: It wasn't me who voted you down, I'll prove it by voting you up. I agree, the question is a bit broad, so this could be an option.

Comment: @NoSssweat No problem... man... i checked it... actually you were also right....the question was quite unclear so i directly wrote the module name...